# Simulate taking a screenshot in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'd like to know how I can simulate a device taking a screenshot in an android emulator. I know how to take a screenshot of a device but I want to simulate someone taking a screenshot with their actual device.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: not sure it will work. But the key combination is power+volume. That in the emaulator is: `power = F7` and `volume = Ctrl+F5 and Ctrl+F6` give a try.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways -

1. From Eclipse: Windows --> Show view --> other --> Devices.
   Once the Devices window is open, you will see a camera icon on the top right side. Click it...
2. From command line -
   Type `adb shell` and once you're "inside" type `screencap name.png` (you'll have to do it in a folder with write permission).
   After that you can exit the shell and type - `adb pull /picture_path/name.png`